# heroku-cliのインストールについて

Tags: macos, heroku

heroku toolbeltのインストールし、アカウント認証しようと

```
   heroku login
```

と入力したところ

```
heroku-cli: Adding dependencies...
 ▸    Get https://cli-assets.heroku.com/node/v5.4.1/node-v5.4.1-darwin-x64.tar.gz: dial tcp: lookup cli-assets.heroku.com on [2404:1a8:7f01:b::3]:53: no such host
 done
heroku-cli: Installing core plugins...
 ▸    

 ▸    fork/exec bin/node: no such file or directory
heroku-cli: Installing core plugins (retrying)...
 ▸    Error installing package. 
 ▸    
 ▸    Try running again with GODE_DEBUG=info to see more output.
heroku-cli: Adding dependencies...
 ▸    Get https://cli-assets.heroku.com/node/v5.4.1/node-v5.4.1-darwin-x64.tar.gz: dial tcp: lookup cli-assets.heroku.com on [2404:1a8:7f01:b::3]:53: no such host
 done
heroku-cli: Installing core plugins...
 ▸    

 ▸    fork/exec bin/node: no such file or directory
heroku-cli: Installing core plugins (retrying)...
 ▸    Error installing package. 
 ▸    
 ▸    Try running again with GODE_DEBUG=info to see more output.
 !    error getting commands pid 7504 exit 1
```

と表示されました。

> ```
>  ▸    fork/exec bin/node: no such file or directory
> ```

このあたりが悪いのだろうと思うのですが、どう対応すれば良いのかわかりません。
対処方法をご存知でしたら、お教えいただけますでしょうか。

Answer (score 0):

表示中段にある「no such host (ホストが見つかりません)」というエラーが怪しい気がします。

https://cli-assets.heroku.com/node/v5.4.1/node-v5.4.1-darwin-x64.tar.gz のダウンロードに失敗しているように見えますが、ブラウザ等からの手動ダウンロードは正常に動作していますか？
もしプロキシを使っている場合は無効にしてから再度コマンドを試してください。

それと念のため、`heroku update`を実行してクライアント本体を更新してみてください。

Comment: ありがとうございます
＞https://cli-assets.heroku.com/node/v5.4.1/node-v5.4.1-darwin-x64.tar.gz
これのダウンロードは正常に動作しているようです。
またプロキシは使っていません。

heroku updateを実行してみましたが、heroku login と同じ処理が走りエラーで終了します。。。

やはり上手くいかないようですね。。他に対処方法ございますでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

下記で解決しました

> cli-assets.heroku.com does not have an IPV6 address, do you have a
>   network configuration that ipv4 disabled or any other special IPV6
>   configuration? I am trying to figure out why it is not falling back to
>   ipv4, when it cannot resolve an ipv6 address.
>
> 出典 | https://github.com/heroku/heroku/issues/1891#issuecomment-181502075

Comment: それはどこに書かれていた文章ですか？引用なら出典を明記すべきです。またその文章を受けて、あなたが何をしたら解決したのでしょうか。

Comment: https://github.com/heroku/heroku/issues/1891
こちらです。
別のネットワークを利用することで解決しました。